# How to updated a single row or column in a table using trigger

Tags: mysql

How do i updated a single row or column in a table using trigger. I am using this query.
SET NEW.Updated_As= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

But it will updated all the value of that row. Kindly help

Comment: Which row do you want updated?  Your question is quite unclear.  Try adding sample data, desired results, and the code that you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Just a generic and simple update query:

> UPDATE table_name SET field1=new-value1, field2=new-value2 [WHERE Clause]

Please refer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for more details about UPDATE

Comment: If you want to update the entire columns then you might not need a where clause. If you want to edit a row/some specific rows of a column then you'll need additional conditions by using WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you need, but if you just want to update a time column with current_timestamp, you don't need a trigger! You can do it just by setting "on update current_timestamp" for your desired field in your table definition.like this:

```
create table test(
.
Updated_As timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp,
.
.
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below syntax would help you,

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `database_name`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trigger_name`$$

CREATE
/*!50017 DEFINER = 'new'@'localhost' */
TRIGGER `trigger_name` AFTER UPDATE ON `updated_table_name` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO new_table_name 
SET ACTION='update',

changedon=NOW();
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

In the above code "Action" and "changedon" are the columns of the "new_table_name".It is written to help the user to be updated about the changes made in the "updated_table_name".